# Angular/ Ui-Grid (ng-grid) / angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am trying to get Angular´s ui-grid running and use the following code:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";

import {BosOverviewComponent} from "./bosoverview.component";

import {UiGridModule} from 'angular-ui-grid';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BosOverviewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    UiGridModule
  ],
  exports: [
    BosOverviewComponent
  ],
})

export class BusinessObjectsModule {
}
```

Using npm start, I always get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at ui-grid.js:8
    at Object.../../../../angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js (ui-grid.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.../../../../angular-ui-grid/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/views/businessobjects/businessobjects.module.ts (bosoverview.component.ts:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts (app.helpers.ts:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (environment.ts:8)
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you [can see](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid#angular-compatibility):

> UI-Grid is currently compatible with Angular versions ranging from 1.4.x to 1.6.x.

You are trying to use it at Angular 2+...

Answer (score 2):

ktretyak is right.  UI-Grid is only officially supported by AngularJS, not Angular 2+.  Fortunately you have options. First, you may be able to make it work anyways. [This github repo](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/ui-grid-angular2), for instance, claims to be an example of UI-Grid working in Angular 2+. And the dev team does [have a plan to upgrade UI-Grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/planning_5.0.md) to Angular 5+, if you are willing to wait.

It may be a better idea, though, to find a library that is officially supported on Angular 2+ now.  Reading through [this discussion](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4294) on the UI-Grid site points you at several data grids that are compatible with Angular 2+.

- If you are already using Angular Material they have a [mat-table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)
- [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) is an Angular component for presenting large and complex data. It has all the features you would expect from any other table but in a light package with no external dependencies. (from the github page)
- [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) makes a set of UI components for Angular 2+. They're open source, [on github](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng), and they have a pretty slick [datatable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable).
- [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) makes "The Best HTML 5 Grid In The World" according to their website. They have [a version](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/#gsc.tab=0) works with Angular 2+. They have a freemium model, but their free version looks nice.
- [angular2-datatable](https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable) is yet another open-source option that, of course, officially supports Angular 2+.

So, don't stress yourself out trying to shoehorn in a library that isn't really built to do what you want it to. It's much easier to use one that is designed to work with Angular 2+.